# Nose test script with command line arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, nose

I would like to be able to run a nose test script which accepts command line arguments. For example, something along the lines:

test.py

```
import nose, sys

def test():
    # do something with the command line arguments
    print sys.argv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.runmodule()
```

However, whenever I run this with a command line argument, I get an error:

```
$ python test.py arg
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named arg)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.1-py2.6.egg/nose/loader.py", line 368, in loadTestsFromName
    module = resolve_name(addr.module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.1-py2.6.egg/nose/util.py", line 334, in resolve_name
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
ImportError: No module named arg

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Apparently, nose tries to do something with the arguments passed in sys.argv. Is there a way to make nose ignore those arguments?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alright, I hate "why would you want to do that?" answers just as much as anyone, but I'm going to have to make one here.  I hope you don't mind.

I'd argue that doing whatever you're wanting to do isn't within the scope of the framework nose.  Nose is intended for *automated* tests.  If you have to pass in command-line arguments for the test to pass, then it isn't automated.  Now, what you *can* do is something like this:

```
import sys

class test_something(object):
    def setUp(self):
        sys.argv[1] = 'arg'
        del sys.argv[2] # remember that -s is in sys.argv[2], see below
    def test_method(self):
        print sys.argv
```

If you run that, you get this output:

```
[~] nosetests test_something.py -s
['/usr/local/bin/nosetests', 'arg']
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

(Remember to pass in the -s flag if you want to see what goes on stdout)

However, I'd probably still recommend against that, as it's generally a bad idea to mess with global state in automated tests if you can avoid it.  What I would likely do is adapt whatever code I'm wanting to test to take an `argv` list.  Then, you can pass in whatever you want during testing and pass in `sys.argv` in production.

**UPDATE**:

> The reason why I need to do it is
>   because I am testing multiple
>   implementations of the same library.
>   To test those implementations are
>   correct I use a single nose script,
>   that accepts as a command line
>   argument the library that it should
>   import for testing.

It sounds like you may want to try your hand at writing a nose plugin.  It's pretty easy to do.  [Here are the latest docs.](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/writing.html)

Comment: The reason why I need to do it is because I am testing multiple implementations of the same library. To test those implementations are correct I use a single nose script, that accepts as a command line argument the library that it should import for testing.

Comment: The link at the end is dead.

Comment: Note that there a lots of good reasons to pass extra context.  Consider that the test starts a web server, you may want to control on which port the server runs to avoid conflicts with other tests (or other running programs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I find I need it for checking programs that call argparse.

Answer (score 13):

You could use another means of getting stuff into your code:

```
import os

print os.getenv('KEY_THAT_MIGHT_EXIST', default_value)
```

Then just remember to set your environment before running nose.

Answer (score 7):

I think that is a perfectly acceptable scenario. I also needed to do something similar in order to run the tests against different scenarios (dev, qa, prod, etc) and there I needed the right URLS and configurations for each environment.

The solution I found was to use the **nose-testconfig** plugin ([link here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig)). It is not exactly passing command line arguments, but creating a config file with all your parameters, and then passing this config file as argument when you execute your nose-tests.

The config file has the following format:

```
[group1]
env=qa

[urlConfig]
address=http://something

[dbConfig]
user=test
pass=test
```

And you can read the arguments using:

```
from testconfig import config

print(config['dbConfig']['user'])
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that to call you use 'nosetests --tc-file qa.conf'

Answer (score 3):

For now I am using the following hack:

```
args = sys.argv[1:]
sys.argv = sys.argv[0:1]
```

which just reads the argument into a local variable, and then deletes all the additional arguments in `sys.argv` so that nose does not get confused by them.

Answer (score 2):

Just running nose and passing in parameters will not work as nose will attempt to interpret the arguments as nose parameters so you get the problems you are seeing.

I do not think nose support parameter passing directly yet but this nose plug-in [nose-testconfig](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig/) Allows you to write tests like below:

```
from testconfig import config
def test_os_specific_code():
    os_name = config['os']['type']
    if os_name == 'nt':
        pass # some nt specific tests
    else:
        pass # tests for any other os
```