# Nose test suite - passing a command argument

Tags: python, nose

was trying to pass a command argument into my nose suits script:

```
from test_cases.test_quick_search import QuickSearchTest

args = ['-s --tc=url:https://our_dev_environment.co']

def run_suite():
    all_tests = TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(QuickSearchTest)
    suite = LazySuite(all_tests)
    run(args,suite=suite)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_suite()
```

but it doesnt seem to do anything

Answer (score 1):

Is `QuickSearchTest` a unittest.TestCase subclass? [loadTestsFromTestCase](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/loader.html#nose.loader.TestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase) will only find tests that are in a `TestCase` subclass. You could have a look at the contents of `all_tests` to see if it actually loaded anything from your module/class.

Assuming `run()` is nosetests [run](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core.html#nose.core.run), using `suite` comes with a pretty hefty warning:

> suite: Suite or list of tests to run (default: None). Passing a suite or lists of tests will bypass all test discovery and loading. ALSO NOTE that if you pass a unittest.TestSuite instance as the suite, context fixtures at the class, module and package level will not be used, and many plugin hooks will not be called. If you want normal nose behavior, either pass a list of tests, or a fully-configured nose.suite.ContextSuite.

You're losing a lot of nosetest utility (setup/teardown at module and class level etc.) by manually assembling and running the tests yourself.

`run` accepts a list of tests for `suite`, so you could try using `suite= all_tests` when invoking it.

Alternatively [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1661171/2175385) might help.